# Why does the preheader contain the content of the body?

Tags: sendwithus

I'm trying to specify a preheader in `SendWithUs`, but I have so rendering issues in `gmail` or `inbox`.

The preheader specified in in the `preheader` tab looks like

```
{% trans %}Hi {{ name }}, you have a new email from XXX {% endtrans %}
```

but I receive the `preheader` plus the start of the `body`

```
- Hi John Doe, you have a new email from XXX logo-color.png Export review data Hi John Doe,...
```

Does someone get the same problem ? Am I doing something wrong ? Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preheader field is just there to guide you toward the idea of inserting some content at the top of your email. Clients such as Gmail will render this "content before the email header" in the list, showing the first few words of the email in the list preview.

Some other platforms make this more explicit by having the first few characters of an email template specifically focused on preheader content.

[image: Example of a preheader in template content]

Sendwithus takes the content in your preheader field and automatically inserts it into the top of the body of the email then uses some styling to hide it from the normal view. **However, it's still just content at the top of the email.** If it's too short, the content following will still show up after the fact.

To stop that additional content from displaying, you can append some `zero-width-joining` characters (`&ZWNJ;&NBSP;`) to the end of the preheader to make the length of the preheader region longer (with whitespace that doesn't add actual space to the template).

Source: https://litmus.com/blog/the-little-known-preview-text-hack-you-may-want-to-use-in-every-email

Comment: To add to @JemBijoux's answer, since Sendwithus supports jinja you can easily add a bit of code to pad the preheader. Try adding something like this `{{ '&ZWNJ;&NBSP;' * 150 }}` after the closing trans block.